# Value Validation

Tags: javascript

Data:

```
var dataArr = [
    {id: 123, str:"Alexey Ayzin", bg:"#FFFFFF"},
    {id: 234, str:"Mira Mdivani"},
    {id: 345, str:"Maria Iliakova"},
    {id: 456, str:"Dennis Ayzin"}
];
```

As you can see, bg:"FFFFFF" exists in one of the subsets, but not the others. How can I change this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < datalength; i++) {
    if(dataArr[i].bg === "undefined"){
        data[i].bg = stringToColour(dataArr[i].str);
    }
}
```

So that it checks each subset for the existence of a BG and if it doesn't exist, fills it with one. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frtvq0hu/4/)

Comment: Remove quotes: `dataArr[i].bg === undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator, if you have falsy values, which are valid.

```
if (!('bg' in dataArr[i])) {
    // set dataArr[i].bg
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If item has bg, don't do anything, else - set new bg

```
var dataArr = [
    {id: 123, str:"Alexey Ayzin", bg:"#FFFFFF"},
    {id: 234, str:"Mira Mdivani"},
    {id: 345, str:"Maria Iliakova"},
    {id: 456, str:"Dennis Ayzin"}
];
dataArr.forEach(function (item){
    item.bg = item.bg || '#FFFFFF';
});

function assignColor(arr, prop, color){
    arr.forEach(function (item){
        item[prop]= item[prop] || color;
    });
}

// usage
assignColor(dataArr, 'bg', '#FFFFFF'); // <== or any other color

// UPDATE
//----------------------------

// get first value of color from array and assign to other
var item = dataArr.find(function(item){ // this will find first item which has defined color
    return !!item.bg;
});
assignColor(dataArr, 'bg', item.bg);
```

Comment: The thing is it could be anything, not just FFFFF. Could I use regex?

Comment: What do you mean, i guess you want to assign different value instead of #FFFFFF?

Comment: Yeah. This will be pretty random data with only str and id guaranteed. The color could be there or not and could be any color. @medettleukabiluly

Comment: Actually, I didn't just want to assign different colors, but i wanted to find any color within the data.@medettleukabiluly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112702/discussion-between-alexey-ayzin-and-medet-tleukabiluly).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
for(var elem in payload.data){
    var isPresent = 0;
    for(var key in payload.data[elem]){
        if(key == "bG"){
            //change boolean if bG is present
            isPresent = 1;
        }
    }
    if(!isPresent){
        bGHex = stringToColour(payload.data[elem].str);
        payload.data[elem].bG = bGHex
    }
```

and then the rest of my code. This worked extremely well, especially after digging deeper into the logic of it.